# Access Azure Cosmos DB from console application

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb

I have created an Azure Cosmos DB account and database, container etc. I am a member of a security group that can access Azure portal and do the above. Now I need to access this database from a console program by c#. The thing is, I do not want to maintain any secrets so I was wondering, is it possible to access the cosmos db with my current Windows login from that console program? Popup prompt to login with my organization user name, which is also my windows login, is ok. It is like when the console is launched, there will be a popup page to ask me to log in. I then choose my organization login/user account to log in.

What I am trying to do is using AD or AAD to do the auths. My windows login is configured in both ad and aad. I do not want to maintain any secret either in local /client side or in key vault.

Comment: As per my understanding, your console app will use the cosmos client library, where you suppose to pass the URL  & the Key. so your console will be using Cosmos as a Rest service. so no Azure pop-up ideally should be coming. As your app shoudn't be access cosmos from Azure UI , instead it will be a service.

Comment: The only alternative to access keys are Roles, but that does not equal the Windows login https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac

Comment: @lokanathdas right. I am trying to access the cosmos as a service using my windows login. Is it possible?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I know it is not equal. I read this and is trying to see if it can apply to my case.  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-integrated-windows-authentication?tabs=dotnet) Desktop app that calls web APIs: Acquire a token using integrated Windows authentication

Comment: @stillNewToEverything i think for that you need to enable the AAD authorization. bec without that , if you access the service with Proper Cosmos Key it may not need your any credential.

Comment: @lokanathdas What I am trying to do is using AD or AAD to do the auths. My windows login is configured in both ad and aad. I do not want to maintain any secret either in local /client side or in key vault.

Comment: Here managed identity will help you. Reference- https://partlycloudy.blog/2021/10/03/secure-azure-cosmos-db-access-by-using-azure-managed-identities/

If you are connected to multi tenant, then mention tenant id. overload is present for DefaultAzureCredential()

Pseudo code:-        
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(); 
 
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(_configuration["Cosmos:Uri"], credential);
var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(_configuration["Cosmos:Db"], _configuration["Cosmos:Container"]);